# Spring save only if doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, h2

I want to save data only if doesn't exist, but not byID but byName for example.

Saving data for me working, but don't want duplicate.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee std) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    myRepoository.save(myRepoository.save(std)
   myRepoository.findById(employee.getId()).orElse(myRepoository.save(std)); //doesn't work
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You're saving the data anyway in the previous line. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Also, `orElse(myRepoository.save(std))` here `save` will *always* be called. If you want to call it only if `employee.getId()` is empty you should use `orElseGet(() -> myRepository.save(std))`

Comment: nope, just delete  myRepoository.findById(employee.getId()).orElse(myRepoository.save(std)) this, and need solution, If if add same name like name what is inside of db, so need doesnt save it.

Comment: Make name column unique.

Comment: bjorke07 ty, working

Answer (score 1):

You may first query the database by name something like:

```
List<Employees> findByName(String empName);
```

then if it does not find any name in the table the list stays empty. Now you have to check if the list size is zero save the data otherwise escape something like:

```
List<Employees> emps = repo.findByName("Mike");
if(!emps.size()>0){
//save the data
}
```

the code is not a working code just trying to give u an idea.

Comment: `if (emps.isEmpty())` might be a better. `if(!emps.size()>0)` is somewhat hard to read.

Comment: Yes that is great. Thanks for your suggestion.